# datum, scalar, vector, matrix and relational theory

Tags: sql, oracle, relational-database

In what theory related to database are the nomenclature *datum* and *vector* used? A colleague mentioned in a legendary way that *datum* refers to scalar values (like a column in a table, making row in this table a *vector*). I do not recall these vocabulary words being used in relational theory. So far I'm seeing the name *Datum* being used to define scalar values in [oracle.sql.Datum](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/class-use/Datum.html).

Comment: On the page that you refer to, `datum` is the name of an Oracle class.  I don't think Oracle class structures are equivalent to "database theory".  It is the singular form of "data", if that helps.  I think both "datum" and "vector" have commonly understood definitions that are useful and not dependent on a particular "theory".

Comment: @gordon-linoff yes, the human-readable definition of *datum* is easy enough and employees at Oracle can use keyboards too but are you suggesting that this relationship between datum and scalar is just "common sense"?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just ask your colleague to explain their remark.

Answer (score 0):

Up to this point in my life, I understood datum to be one of the models used in GIS projections. The Oracle class definition just makes for boneheaded documentation.  I found a reference to [Datum in Postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xfunc-c.html).  That usage makes sense because it is a C definition of a return type.  I'd stick with scalar because that seems to be the more common use.  Then again I didn't start using the scalar word until I started using scalar queries some time ago.  :-)